# fcntl.h doesn't contain all status flag constants

Tags: constants, definition, fcntl

I have been going through header files and I'm not able to find any file with status flag definitions (like O_RDONLY).

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

If you're on Linux, it should be in `/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h`.

```
#define O_RDONLY 00
```

You can find it using `rgrep`, or `ctags` and `Vim`, or `cpp`, or `cwhere`.

---

**rgrep**

The simplest way is to use `rgrep`, a.k.a. `grep -R`.

```
$ rgrep O_WRONLY .
./X11/Xw32defs.h:#  define O_WRONLY    _O_WRONLY
./linux/fs.h: * to O_WRONLY and O_RDWR via the strange trick in __dentry_open()
./linux/smbno.h:#define SMB_O_WRONLY    0x0001
./asm-generic/fcntl.h:#define O_WRONLY  00000001
./security/_pam_macros.h:    if ((fd = open(_PAM_LOGFILE, O_WRONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_APPEND)) != -1) {
./security/_pam_macros.h:    if ((fd = open(_PAM_LOGFILE, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND)) != -1) {
./security/_pam_macros.h:    if ((fd = open(_PAM_LOGFILE, O_WRONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_APPEND)) != -1) {
./security/_pam_macros.h:    if ((fd = open(_PAM_LOGFILE, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND)) != -1) {
./bits/fcntl.h:#define O_WRONLY      01
```

---

**ctags**

Or, you could run `ctags -R` in `/usr/include` and then run `vim -t O_WRONLY`.

Or, a bit better, but more typing:

```
find . /usr/include -name "*.h" | 
ctags -f - -L - |
grep "^O_WRONLY   " |
cut -d "    " -f 1,2,3 |
sed -e 's# /\^#    #;s#\$/\;"$##'
```

---

**cpp**

The best way I have found is using `cpp`.

Assuming you have a source file called YOUR_SOURCE_FILE with the necessary `#include`s, try running:

```
cpp -dD YOUR_SOURCE_FILE | less
```

Then search for your `#define`, e.g. `/O_WRONLY`, then scroll up to find the first file name above it.  In this case:

```
# 27 "/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h" 2 3 4
```

means that `O_WRONLY` is being picked up from `/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h` if you include the three header files mentioned in `man fcntl`.

---

**cwhere**

I have a script called `cwhere` to automate running `cpp`:

```
$ cwhere O_WRONLY sys/types.h sys/stat.h fcntl.h
/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h: #define O_WRONLY 01
```

[Download cwhere here](http://svn.mikelward.com/svn/scripts/cwhere)

If `desc` is installed, you can just type the name of the function that uses that `#define`, e.g.

```
$ cwhere O_WRONLY 'fcntl()'
/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h: #define O_WRONLY 01
```

[Download desc here](http://svn.mikelward.com/svn/scripts/desc)

Comment: checking expanded file was useful. :)

Comment: i wonder why there are 2 fcntl.h files. one in usr/include and another in usr/include/bits

Comment: Please ask that as another question.  I will try to answer it there.